# Проблема с установкой ловушек SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c++, winapi

Мне необходимо написать программу для перехвата нажатых клавиш. Приложение работает без окна, поэтому не выполняется команда

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, hookfunc, LoadLibrary("HookDll.dll"),0)
```

Программа не реагирует на потоки других приложений. Как это исправить?

Comment: А эта "команда" возвращает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понял этого:

```
  Приложение работает без окна, поэтому не выполняется команда
```

То есть, по-вашему, приложение "без окна" не может взаимодействовать с внутренними функциями системы !? На самом деле это чушь. Все зависит от подключаемых библиотек.

---

Вместо первого параметра **"WH_KEYBOARD"**(=14) используйте **"WH_KEYBOARD_LL"**(= 13).
(Интересно было бы посмотреть на момент загрузки функции обработки хука *hookfunc()* из DLL`ки )

---

```
Программа не реагирует на потоки других приложений
```

Хук на то и хук, что он глобальный, отлавливает все события, связанные с группой событий в момент его регистрации...

Comment: typedef int (CALLBACK* lpfn)();
HHOOK hook;
lpfn hookfunc;
HINSTANCE hDLL=LoadLibrary("HookDll.dll");
hookfunc=(lpfn)GetProcAddress(hDLL,"KeyboardProc");
hook=SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, 
hookfunc, LoadLibrary("HookDll.dll"),0);

вот так хук загружается

Comment: Все вроде бы хорошо, но почему вы не передаете функции регистрации хука уже существующий идентификатор подгруженной библиотеки "hDLL"?

---
Первый параметр - WH_KEYBOARD_LL(=13)